# Angular directive stops working after being moved from one DOM element to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a `modal` service in my app that opens/closes a modal. When the modal is opened, it plucks its `content` from the div with the specified id, which always sits inside a container `elem` that is hidden. Normally this works fine.

The problem I'm having now is that when a user opens the modal with the `mediaBrowser` directive for the first time, they can navigate between the photos/videos tab and select an item to attach to a post. If the modal is closed and reopened though, nothing works. The photos load as expected, but clicking one does nothing. It's as if none of the functions in the `mediaBrowser` or `mediaBrowserPhotos` directive work.

I thought it might have something to do with needing to `compile` the directive after its moved from one DOM element to another, but I've not had much luck resolving it with the `$compile` service.

Here is my `modal` service:

```
app.service('modal', [function() {
    var modal = this;
    modal.settings = {};
    modal.overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    modal.modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    modal.content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    modal.closeBtn = $('<div id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></div>');

    modal.modal.hide();
    modal.overlay.hide();
    modal.modal.append(modal.content, modal.closeBtn);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append(modal.overlay, modal.modal);
    });

    modal.open = function (settings) {
        modal.settings = settings;
        var content = modal.settings.content;

        modal.content.empty().append(content);
        if(modal.settings.class) modal.modal.addClass(modal.settings.class);
        if(modal.settings.height) modal.modal.css({ height: settings.height });
        if(modal.settings.width) modal.modal.css({ width: settings.width });
        if(modal.settings.content_height) modal.modal.css({ height: settings.content_height });
        if(modal.settings.content_width) modal.modal.css({ width: settings.content_width });
        if(modal.settings.fitToWindow) {
            modal.settings.width = $(window).width() - 160;
            modal.settings.height = $(window).height() - 160;
        };
        center(modal.settings.top);

        $(window).bind('resize.modal', center);
        modal.modal.show();
        modal.overlay.show();

        $(modal.closeBtn).add(modal.overlay).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            modal.close();
        });
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                modal.close();
                $(document).unbind('keyup');
            }
        })
    };

    modal.close = function() {
        var elem = modal.settings.elem;
        var content = modal.settings.content;

        elem.empty().append(content);

        modal.modal.hide();
        modal.overlay.hide();
        modal.content.empty();
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    function center(top) {
        if(!top || !isInt(top)) top = 130;
        var mLeft = -1 * modal.modal.width() / 2;
        modal.modal.css({
            top: top + 'px',
            left: '50%',
            marginLeft: mLeft
        });
        function isInt(n) {
           return n % 1 === 0;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I also have a `mediaBrowser` directive in my app, which housed 2 child directives representing a photos and videos tab. Here is my `mediaBrowser` directive:

```
app.directive('mediaBrowser', ['$rootScope', 'profileAPI', 'photosAPI', 'videosAPI', function($rootScope, profileAPI, photosAPI, videosAPI) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/employers/media_browser.html',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            card: '=',
            type: '=',
            photoContainer: '=',
            videoContainer: '=',
            mediaBrowserContainer: '=',
            mediaBrowserForm: '='
        }, controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'profileAPI', 'photosAPI', 'videosAPI', function($scope, $rootScope, profileAPI, photosAPI, videosAPI) {
            $scope.mediaView = profileAPI.mediaView;
            resize($scope.mediaView);

            $rootScope.$on('mService:keyChanged', function resultsUpdated(event, value) {
                $scope.mediaView = profileAPI.mediaView;
                resize($scope.mediaView);
            });

            $scope.setMediaView = function(view) {
                profileAPI.mediaView = view;
            };

            function resize(resource) {
                if(resource === 'photos') {
                    photosAPI.resizeColumns('#media_browser_photos_new_' + $scope.type);
                } else if (resource === 'videos') {
                    videosAPI.resizeColumns('#media_browser_videos_new_' + $scope.type);
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Here is the partial for the `mediaBrowser` directive:

```
<div style="display:none" id="{{mediaBrowserContainer}}">
    <div id="{{mediaBrowserForm}}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row subheader modal-tabs">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-class="{'active-sub': mediaView === 'photos'}">
                            <a ng-click="setMediaView('photos');">Photos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{'active-sub': mediaView === 'videos'}">
                            <a ng-click="setMediaView('videos');">Videos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-if="mediaView === 'photos'">
            <div media-browser-photos
                model="model"
                container="photoContainer"
                media-browser-container="mediaBrowserContainer"
                media-browser-form="mediaBrowserForm"
                for-type="type"
                mode="'new'">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-if="mediaView === 'videos'">
            <div media-browser-videos
                model="model"
                container="videoContainer"
                media-browser-container="mediaBrowserContainer"
                media-browser-form="mediaBrowser"
                for-type="type"
                mode="'new'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `mediaBrowserPhotos` directive. Note that the videos version is basically identical to photos:

```
app.directive('mediaBrowserPhotos', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', 'photosAPI', 'modal', function($rootScope, $timeout, $q, photosAPI, modal) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/employers/media_browser_photos.html',
        scope: {
            container: '=',
            model: '=',
            mediaBrowserContainer: '=',
            mediaBrowserForm: '=',
            forType: '=',
            mode: '='
        }, controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', 'photosAPI', 'modal', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $q, photosAPI, modal) {
            $scope.current_page = photosAPI.current_page;
            $scope.results = [];
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.num_pages = 0;
            $scope.page_numbers = photosAPI.page_numbers;
            $scope.total_count = 0;
            $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.order = false;
            var thumbSize = 150;
            var q = $scope.current_page;

            $rootScope.$on('cService:keyChanged', function resultsUpdated(event, value) {
                $scope.results = photosAPI.results;
                $scope.loading = photosAPI.loading;
                $scope.num_pages = photosAPI.num_pages;
                $scope.page_numbers = photosAPI.page_numbers;
                $scope.total_count = photosAPI.total_count;
            });

            $scope.selectMedia = function(options) {
                if($scope.mode === 'new') {
                    var content = '#add_card_form';
                    var elem = '#add_card_form_container';
                } else {
                    var content = '#' + $scope.forType + '_' + $scope.model.id + '_form';
                    var elem = '#' + $scope.forType + '_' + $scope.model.id + '_form_container';
                };

                $scope.model[options.type] = options.object;
                modal.close();
                modal.open({
                    content: $(content),
                    elem: $(elem),
                    height: '594px',
                    content_height: '578px'
                })
            }
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Here is the partial for `mediaBrowserPhotos`:

```
<div class="column-layout cols-3 search-results-no-resize" id="{{container}}">
    <div class="multiple-photo-upload media">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ng-click="orderAsc();">
            Sort by Date
            <a href="#" ng-show="order">Oldest First <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="font-size: 1.3em;"></i></a>
            <a href="#" ng-show="!order">Newest First <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size: 1.3em;"></i></a>
        </button>
        <div class="paginator" ng-if="page_numbers.length > 1">
            <div class="page-btn prv" ng-click="prevPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
            <div class="page-btn" ng-repeat="p in page_numbers" ng-class="{'current':p === current_page}" ng-click="loadPage(p)">{{p}}</div>
            <div class="page-btn nxt" ng-click="nextPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="results-label media"><b>{{total_count}}</b>&nbsp;<span ng-if="total_count == 1">Photo</span><span ng-if="total_count != 1">Photos</span></div>
    <div class="media-browser photos" ng-show="!loading && total_count > 0">
        <div class="col">
            <div ng-repeat="r in results" class="card result-link">
                <div class="content result">
                    <div class="image-container" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + r.image_url + ')'}" ng-click="$parent.selectMedia({object: r, type: 'image'})"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="col" style="display:none"></div>
        <br style="clear:both" />
    </div>
    <div ng-show="loading" class="loading-results">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

The whole app itself is pretty complex and difficult to reproduce in a Plucker/Fiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know of you need any additional code from the app!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of moving the whole thing, wrap it in another element, leave that one in place and move the same element you were moving now (now the child of the element in your link function).

If you don't use `replace:true`, which is deprecated anyway, you get that element for free (the directive's element).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate a bit?